# How to prevent conversation exit in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have enabled a webhook for my cancel event in Dialogflow.

I need to check the current stage of the flow and in case if it is payment or transfer I just need to go the the main flow without closing the entire conversation.

However, I see that the application is not allowing me to prevent exit. It forces the conversation to exist anyhow. Can someone please help? Any other workaround I can use to prevent exit to handle the condition I have?

Here is the cancel event code written in node.js using actions-on-google framework.

```
 app.intent('askCancel', (conv) => {  

   if (conv.user.storage.isTransfer || conv.user.storage.isPayment) {
     conv.ask("Ok we have cancelled the transaction. What else would you like to do?")
     deleteContext(conv);
     conv.contexts.set('ask-service-context', 5);
     return;
   }  

   conv.user.storage = {};
   conv.close("Thank you for using the application. Have a nice day.");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

This would be like a browser window that doesn't close because the page author is blocking the close event.

The user has final control about closing the Action - the best you can do is to save state and warn them that's what they've done, and that they can restart it again in the future.